# How to test solvability of a Diophantine equation?

Tags: expression-test, diophantine-equations

When applying the [BRC theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruck%E2%80%93Ryser%E2%80%93Chowla_theorem) I need to test if an equation has a non-zero solution in integers.

The equation is of form:

$$x^2 + by^2 + cz^2 = 0$$

We could try to directly check if this equation has a non-trivial solution. The trivial is always there, so if there at least two in total, we're good:

```
nonTrivSolQ1[b_, c_] := Length[FindInstance[x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2 == 0, {x, y, z}, Integers, 2]] >= 2
```

But sometimes we get a false with an asterisk:

```
FindInstance::fwsol: Warning: FindInstance found only 1 instance(s), but it was not able to prove 2 instances do not exist.
```

And in some of these cases the false is wrong. We can use [Legendre theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Legendre_theorem) to test solvability of the equation. In this case the solvability is equal to solvability of these two congruences:

$$u^2 \equiv -c (\textrm{mod}\ |b|)$$
$$v^2 \equiv -b (\textrm{mod}\ |c|)$$

However I have no better idea to test solvability here than to find instances again:

```
nonTrivSolQ2[b_, c_] := 
 Length[FindInstance[v^2 == -b, {v}, Modulus -> Abs[c]]] > 0 && 
  Length[FindInstance[v^2 == -c, {v}, Modulus -> Abs[b]]] > 0
```

This seems to work better, but is it safe that it never misses a solution when one exists? Or maybe there are other tools to test the solvability?

## Edit

This seems a more reliable test than `nonTrivSolQ2`.

```
nonTrivSolQ3[b_, c_] := 
 Length@PowerModList[-b, 1/2, Abs[c]] > 0 && 
  Length@PowerModList[-c, 1/2, Abs[b]] > 0
```

Still this is "find the solution!" not "is there a solution?". Also, can I somehow use `PowerMod` and turn `PowerMod::root: The equation x^2 = 10 (mod 14) has no integer solutions.` into `False`?

Comment: The function that is meant to return confident results is `Reduce`: `Reduce@Exists[{x, y, z}, Element[x | y | z, Integers], 
  x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2 == 0 && (x != 0 || y != 0 || z != 0)]`.  Here it will fail on many `b` and `c` choices.  But at least it gives a clear answer: "yes", "no", or "I don't know".

Comment: I do not know if this is any different from `FindInstance`.  But at least *in principle* it could use methods which don't require finding a specific instance.

Comment: "...can I somehow use `PowerMod`..." - try `Quiet[Check[PowerMod[10, 1/2, 14]; True, False, PowerMod::root]]`

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513733/solving-a-diophantine-equation-of-the-form-x2-ay2-byz-cz2-with-the-co/1514030#1514030